# Can jhipster be used as just a core infrastructure code generator?

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster

I've been working on building a custom crud application in springboot and recently stumbled upon jhipster. Jhipster seems to have a lot of the core infrastructure components I need to setup, Security, social login, jwt, angular etc. Beyond setting up core infrastructure, I would like to continue with my custom app design.

I'm wondering if you can manually create entities, controllers, and services along with a custom frontend, or are you required to use the code generator to generate entities etc?

I copied my entity package over from the custom springboot app I've been building into my jhipster application. I'm noticing jhipster never picked up my new entity classes.

Answer (score 1):

JHipster is just a code generator, once the code has been generated,it's all yours you can customize it as you want. All you need is to understand its technology stack: spring Boot,JPA,Angular or React, ...

So if your existing entities are not being picked up, it probably means that your entity package is not a subpackage of JHipster main application class and you did not add `@EntityScan` annotation to scan your own package.